# ASP.NET MVC Webgrid display multiple columns in a single row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a Asp.net MVC grid. 
My problem is I need to display multiple columns in a single row.
For example:

Name        Date             Compensation
Id                           USD  - 99999
Grade                        INR -  99999

The above layout is a single row in the grid.

All the columns (Name, Id, Grade, Curency1, Amount1, Currency2, Amount2 ) are available in a single record as separate columns. Here Currency1 means USD and Currency2 means INR.

Any ideas how to do this. I am using a strongly typed model and EF6.

Comment: To further refine the example
Name                Date                  Compensation
Id
Grade

Mr XBCD            30-May-2014             USD 6000
123456                                     INR 360000
Grade 2

Hope this clarifies further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to create a separate 'type' and model for each multi-faceted column, then try to display this type in the webgrid (which I show is possible in the latter part of my example).

For example:

Create a new 'type' (or 'column') class called CompensationColumn:

```
...
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace yourproject.Columns  // I put this in its own namespace/folder - you don't have to
{
    public class CompensationColumn
    {
        public string Currency1 { get; set; }
        public int Amount1 { get; set; }
        public string Currency2 { get; set; }
        public int Amount2 { get; set; }

        public CompensationColumn(string currency_1, int amount_1, string currency_2, int amount_2)
        {
            Currency1 = currency_1;
            Amount1 = amount_1;
            Currency2 = currency_2;
            Amount2 = amount_2;
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a file called CompensationColumn.cshtml in the yourproject/Shared/EditorTemplates folder (if the Shared folder doesn't exist you can also create a your view/DisplayTemplates folder).  Define how this column will look, as if it was a custom 'type' (modify this to your liking):

```
@model yourproject.Columns.CompensationColumn
@if (Model != null)
{
    @Model.Currency1<text> - </text>@Model.Amount1<text><p/></text>
    @Model.Currency2<text> - </text>@Model.Amount2
}
else
{
}
```

Then in your Models folder, create a partial class to extend your current EF table model (file name shouldn't matter).  I am going to assume your table is 'employee_table'.  I am also adding Metadata for the model in this class as it is a good place to put it if you are using a database-first design:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using yourproject.Columns;

namespace yourproject.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeModelMetaData))]  // This links the metadata class below
    public partial class employee_table  // This should be the EF class name
    {
        [DisplayName("Compensation")]
        public CompensationColumn Compensation { get; set; }  // Here we add a new field for your row
    }

    public class EmployeeModelMetaData
    {
        // copy your EF class fields here and decorate them with dataannotations.  This is helpful
        // if you are using a database-first design as it won't get overwritten when db changes.
        [DisplayName("Id")]
        public int emp_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Amount")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public int emp_amount1 { get; set; }
        // etc . . .
    }
}
```

I make a few assumptions here about a database-first design, but you should be able to figure out how to adapt it to a code-first design if needed.

If you also need to edit elements this column type together, then you would need to create a model binder, but I'm not going there since you only mentioned displaying it.

To get the display template to display in the webgrid, you will need to `format:` the columns of the webgrid.  In your view with an IEnumerable model (e.g. your Index view):

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    List<WebGridColumn> columns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    WebGridColumn col = grid.Column(columnName: "Col3", header: "Compensation", format: (item) =>
    {
        yourproject.Columns.CompensationColumn c = item.Compensation; return Html.DisplayFor(model => c); 
    } );
    columns.Add(col);                                                                                                                                
}
@grid.GetHtml(columns: columns)
```

This last snippet I adapted from Frédéric Blondel's code [here](http://www.nelite.com/community/b/fblondel/archive/2012/05/29/asp-net-mvc-3-set-a-displaytemplate-to-a-webgrid-column.aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Your welcome! Please let me know if I can clarify any particular part of the answer or if you need further help.